# ubuntu: apport.service can not be started and systemctl status shows active (exited)

Tags: systemd

I am using ubuntu 21.10 and a program is keeping crashing. I'd like to see the core dump. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109747/871095), it seems that I need to use the `apport.service`.

But I observe the following about the `apport.service`

- the status of `apport.service` is `active (exited)` by running `systemctl status apport.service`.
- `ps -ef | grep apport` shows there is no apport process running

I also did `sudo systemctl stop apport.service` followed by `sudo systemctl start apport.service`. The result is the same.

What does the `active (exited)` status mean? How can I start the `apport` service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`active (exited)` will appear when a service uses `Type=oneshot` with `RemainAfterExit=true`.

The following basic service will start on `systemctl start ...`, exit immediately with a success, then remain "active" until it is stopped.

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

This can be particularly useful when using the `PartOf=` relationship with other units.  In that case, a unit would start and do something, then trigger other units to start.  When that first unit is stopped (even though it finished on start), other other units would also stop.

---

I don't run Ubuntu, so I don't have `apport`, but I imagine that as long as the service isn't `inactive (dead)` or `failed`, then it's working as intended.

The process it ran on start could have loaded a kernel module, or something that `apport.service` `Wants=` or `Requires=` could be doing something.

When something crashes, check for a dump in `/var/crash/` (the file name is composed from the name of the crashed executable and the user id).  If it isn't there, you may need to enable some crash reporting in `/etc/apport/crashdb.conf` (see [Ubuntu's wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport)).

> Note: According to Ubuntu's wiki, apport may upload crashes to somewhere. Your data may not be private.